# Why does the exception handler work when the zero division error is inside the else clause but not in the commented out line below

Tags: python, exception

Working on exception handling in python, in the code below the `print(n/0)` line currently executes the `except` `ZeroDivisionError` print statement. But if I were to delete `print(n/0)` and uncomment out `print(5/0)` it doesn't, just returns the standard zerodivision error statement. Why is this?

```
def factorial(n):
    #where n<=1 = n, else n= n*(n-1)!
    """calculates n recursively"""

    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        print(n/0)
        return n*factorial(n-1)

# print(5/0) 


try:
    factorial(1000)
except RecursionError:
    print("this program can't calculate numbers that large")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("What are you doing dividing by zero?")

print("program terminating")
```

Comment: Because it's not called from inside the `try` block;

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question but I am assuming you are asking why doesn't print(5/0) throws the exception that you defined? If so, it is because that exception handler is declared to work when the function call to factorial() throws an error. The statement print(5/0) is not the part of factorial().

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for!